# Topic subscriber connection in Tibco

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, jms-topic, tibco-business-works

I have a process that starts with a topic subscriber.
What happens with a topic subscriber in Tibco if the EMS server shuts down?

I guess it will reconnect. But how many times or for how long it will try to reconnect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour depends on various settings, set either on the client or server.

If you for example use a Java client you can set the behaviour through the connection factory:

`TibjmsConnectionFactory.setReconnAttemptCount(10);
TibjmsConnectionFactory.setReconnAttemptDelay(1000);
TibjmsConnectionFactory.setReconnAttemptTimeout(1000);`

You also can configure this behaviors on the server by using JNDI connections. Those can be defined through the `factories.conf` file.

BusinessWorks 5 does not reconnect by default, but honors all JNDI propagated settings.

Comment: I'm using BW5 as the client and the server is EMS. So it will reconnect based on these settings. Do you know what are the default values?

Comment: By default, BW5 does not set any reconnect behavior, so it looses the connection on disconnect. In EMS this can be set by JNDI, but this is also not set by default.

Answer (score 0):

It will try to connect indefinitely.